# Problems with understanding how recursion works in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm learning about functions in C from the book *C Programming: A Modern Approach*. It contains the following function:

```
int fact(int n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

with the following explanation:

> To see how recursions works,  let's trace the execution of the
>   statement `i = fact(3);` here is what happens: "
>
> ```
> fact(3) finds that 3 is not equal or less than 1, so it calls
>    fact(2)which finds that 2 is not equal or less than 1, so it calls
>       fact(1) which finds that 1 is equal or less than 1, so it returns 1,causing
>    fact(2) to return  2 x 1 = 2, causing
> fact(3) to return 3 x 2 = 6
> ```

I'm really confused, why does it does all these actions if it is not inside a loop? why does it keep making the 3 less and less until it matches the argument in if function?

Does the * symbol means that n in the fact(n) is now 3 - 1 and it basically says it do it all over again?

Comment: @tacocat You will really love [this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/trace-recursion.html) link.This is how to trace back recursion.

Comment: This link may also help you understand recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768992/problems-with-understanding-how-functions-work-in-c#27768992 :-)

Comment: See [Understanding how recursive functions work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work)

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is the process when a function calls itself.
In the function definition you can see a call to `fact(n-1)`, this means the function itself is called again.

```
int fact(int n) //return value is an integer, name of function is "fact", input argument is an integer named n
{
  if (n <= 1) // if the input arg equals 1, return 1
    return 1;
  else 
    return n * fact(n - 1); //else, return n (input arg of this fact) times the return value of fact(n - 1)
}
```

Fact(3) is supposed to return 3 * 2 * 1 = 6. 
What happens when process the statement `int a = fact(3)` is the following:

```
fact(3) //dive into this function:
{
  if (n <= 1) //n is not 1
    return 1;
  else
    return n * fact(n - 1); //now we call fact(2)
}
```

we call fact(2):

```
{
  if (n <= 1) //n is not 1
    return 1;
  else
    return n * fact(n - 1); //now we call fact(1)
}
```

we call fact(1):

```
{
  if (n <= 1) //n equals 1
    return 1; //return 1
  else
    return n * fact(n - 1); 
}
```

Now function `fact(1)` returns 1 to the point where its called, which is inside `fact(2)`.
To be precise, to the statement `return 2*fact(1);`, this gets passed back to the statement `return 3*fact(2);` which gets passed back to our initial function call and our integer 'a' gets the value 6.

I hope this made it more clear to you, if you have still questions left feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just going  by your example to find the factorial of 3

The first call is `fact(3)`

`n = 3` so else condition gets executed

```
3 * fact(2)
```

`n = 2` so else condition gets executed

```
2 * fact(1)
```

`n = 1` now if condition passes so it returns 1

So put together

```
3 * fact(2)

3 * 2 * fact(1)

3 * 2 * 1 = 6
```

There has to be a exit condition in recursion in this it is

```
if(n = 1) /* 0! = 1 So you have reached the last iteration and you are good to return */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function from within itself it's called recursion. Since you return the value 
returned from the internal call, the function gets evaluated until it doesn't call itself anymore i.e. when `n <= 1`, `<` is just to account for `0! == 1`.

It makes `3` or `n` less and less because of

```
fact(n - 1) // n - 1 < n
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursion occurs when `fact(n-1)` is called. There the function itself is called again, thus the code repeats itself without the need of a loop. The argument value changes because the function is called with a different argument each time.

Btw, the `*` symbol means a multiplication.