# Recursion: don't understand this result

Tags: c, recursion

```
void func(int num){
    if(num< 3){
        printf("%d ", num);
        func(num+ 1);
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
}
```

Suppose I call this function with func(0).
Why is the result 0 1 2 2 1 0 ? 
I don't know why it's decreasing.

Comment: The first three numbers come from the first printf, and the second three numbers come from the second printf as the stack unwinds. To see that better, try `"a:%d "` and `"b:%d "` as the format strings.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but why is it going from 2 to 0, it doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: Your code does nothing since the function is never called.

Comment: Yeah I call it in the main, didn't think it was necessary to post that....

Comment: Try to ask yourself, **when** does the second `printf` get called on any iteration?

Comment: In your original question you didn't even state what value you called it with. Readers shouldn't need to infer that (not that it is very hard).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with understanding how recursion works in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768992/problems-with-understanding-how-recursion-works-in-c), or [Understanding recursion in the beer bottle example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20714617/69809), or [Understanding how recursive functions work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25676961/69809).

Comment: Sorry John. Thanks for the help guys, I understand now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a stack trace

```
f(0)
    print 0
    f(1)
        print 1
        f(2)
            print 2
            f(3)  // 3 < 3 == false
            print 2
         print 1
     print 0
```

Comment: Okay cool so I get why 3 is false and it prints out 2. But why does it also print 1 and 0 after that?

Comment: When you call a function (B) inside another one (A), you do not interrupt the function (A), you stack it and return to it once the called function (B) finishes

Comment: Wow thanks, I never thought of that. This cleared things up a lot.

Comment: I am happy my post helped you :) @GillesVanHooff