# return is not breaking my recursive function in c

Tags: c, recursion

```
struct Node *xFromEnd(struct Node *pHead, int x)
{
    static int temp = 1;

    if (pHead->next != NULL)
        xFromEnd(pHead->next, x);
    if ((temp++) == x)
        return pHead;
}
```

How do I break out of the function when the condition is met? The return is just going further up on the call stack(going to its previous function call) rather than exiting and going to main. How can I do that?

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work) question first.

Comment: I understand that. Recursion is climbing up a ladder one step at a time and then climbing down one step at a time. What I'm asking is can I jump straight down once I've found my "step" like in this case?

Comment: If you want, you can use something like dynamic programming and then you can break when you find your answer.

Comment: `temp == x` for only one value of `temp`. That should give you a hint re: your ladder.

Comment: That's correct. And if that one value is found, is there a way I should be able to come straight out of the call stack? I know what I'm doing wrong here, it's just that I want to know what I'm imagining is possible or not at all in c.

Comment: You might want to start with adding an explanation of what you are trying to achieve in the first place.

Comment: There is, but first you should understand what your code _actually_ does. Step through it, or insert some logging statements, or follow it on paper. When `temp >= x`, your bug will become apparent.

Comment: I used breakpoint to step through the process. I go till the end of the list(say 10 steps up the steps till it reaches NULL) in the first if condition statement. Then say I want the 3rd value from the end(x=3). So i step through it, and when the condition is met(temp == x), I have found my value and want to return. So the line: return pHead; is executed. However, this return instead of going to main, just goes on to the next fucntion call. Which i now understand is correct behavior and it will do so till all steps(in our case 10) are completed. 

Can I come straight out to the main? If yes how

Comment: @ dhke - I'm trying to find the xth number from back of the link list. Data available to me is head of the list and x.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node *xFromEnd(struct Node *pHead, int x){
    static int temp = 1;//but can not reset !!

    if(pHead == NULL)
        return NULL;
    struct Node *p = xFromEnd(pHead->next, x);
    if (p == NULL){
        return (x == temp++) ? pHead : NULL;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing a solution, however I see that 'p' is getting returned unnecessarily even after x==temp condition is met where pHead is returned. I would like to find a way to avoid this. Hence my question is, is it possible to break out straight to main once pHead is returned?

Comment: In the case of C does not allow you to straight return to main.

Comment: There is a need for global escape from the recursive call.(c++ have try..catch, but...)

Comment: or use `longjmp`...they deviate from the spirit that returns a value.

Answer (score -2):

I think than your function never break because in your function you have an increment of temp variable which return true value, and not the value of temp variable.

Try :

```
temp++;
if (temp == x)
return pHead;
```