# Why does this recursive loop equal 200?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to understand why this outputs 200 because I would think that each time is adds 2+ (w-1) each time until w = 0 - wouldn't the output be much larger? Thanks!

```
int w = 100;
public static int mystery(int w)
{
  if (w<=0) {
  return 0;
  }
  return 2+ mystery(w-1);
}
```

Comment: Work it out on paper. Try passing in 0, 1, 2, 3... see if you can generalize the pattern. (Try running the code with those inputs, use a debugger to step through the execution to help you see if you need it).

Comment: It seems you are adding 2, 100 times and same is the output. Andy is correct, use debug and check.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29188074/1597897

Answer (score 6):

`mystery(100)` calls `mystery(99)` which calls `mystery(98)`, ..., which calls `mystery(1)`, which calls `mystery(0)`, where the recursion ends.

i.e. there are 101 calls, each of them (except of the last one, which returns `0`) adds `2` to the value returned by the recursive call. A 100 times 2 equals 200.

In other words

```
mystery(0) returns 0
mystery(1) returns 2 + mystery(0) == 2
mystery(2) returns 2 + mystery(1) == 4
...
mystery(99) returns 2 + mystery(98) == 198
mystery(100) returns 2 + mystery(99) == 200
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursion continues until w becomes 0.so function gets called for 101 times and adds 2 for 100 times.