# recursive labyrinth program / pathfinder

Tags: java, recursion, methods

This is a snippet of a code that works as a pathfinder, and it uses a recursive method. I don't quite see how it works though. So, we let the user create the labyrinth, and after he did, we start the method findRek in the main method. We check whether some field is a wall or a path that we already walked on (marked by a " - "). We want to mark every field that is not the start but is still free.

In the second paragraph, we work with the principle of recursion, checking top, down, left and right - that's were I'm lost. So the method is calling itself here, but under what circumstances does it return a "true"? Only when the field that we stand on is the goal? Plus, what happens here if we get a "false" after calling the method again with a certain direction? Does it check every direction then?

The last paragraph in the recursive method sets the field we are standing on as free since it was marked as a path before, which would always lead to a false.

```
private static boolean findRek(char[][] lab, int x, int y) {

if (lab [y][x] == GOAL)
  return true;
if (lab [y][x] == WALL)
  return false;
if (lab [y][x] == PATH)
  return false;
if (lab [y][x] != START)
  lab[y][x] = PATH;

if (findRek(lab, x, y-1))
  return true;
if (findRek(lab, x+1, y))
  return true;
if (findRek(lab, x, y+1))
  return true;
if (findRek(lab, x-1, y))
  return true;

lab[y][x] = FREE;
  return false;
}

...

public static void main(String[]args) {

boolean yes = findRek(lab);
if(yes) {

...
```

Since this was called a possible duplicate: It's not like I didn't understand recursion in genereal, but I don't quite get the operating principle of the boolean variables here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding how recursive functions work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work)

Comment: Why? This question is specifically about boolean variables, it's not like I didn't understand recursion in general.

Comment: From reading your question I gather that your problem is understanding how recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

> So the method is calling itself here, but under what circumstances does it return a "true"?

Each recursion is basically taking one step forward. Once it reaches the `GOAL` (which takes X steps, i.e. X recursive calls), the first `if` statement returns `true`, and when a recursive call returns `true`, the method will also return `true`, so when it hit the `GOAL`, the entire recursion call stack will be unwound by X `return true` statements.

> Only when the field that we stand on is the goal?

That's what triggers the unwinding, leading to the initial call returning `true`, i.e. path to goal was found, and the path to the goal is left marked in the maze.

> Plus, what happens here if we get a "false" after calling the method again with a certain direction?

When a step forward, aka a recursive call, hits a `WALL` or `PATH`, it'll return `false`, indicating "wrong direction". The caller will then skip to try another direction. If all 4 directions end in "wrong direction", we're obvious on the wrong path to the goal, so the method will undo stepping to the current location and return `false`, so the previous step can try it's other directions. This is called *[backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)*.

> Does it check every direction then?

Until it finds the `GOAL`, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, for example, when we stand at point P, and then we head 3 steps to the right like P -> P_1 -> P_2 -> P_3, the programm returns "true" in all of these cases and marks every step, but when he hits a WALL at P_3 -> WALL, he checks the top and the bottom, but when he hits a WALL again in those cases, he goes back to P and sets it back to FREE?

Comment: *"programm returns "true" in all of these cases"* If "right" is the first direction checked (it's not, but let's assume it was), and you make 3 steps to the right, then no call has returned yet, so no return of *any* `true` or `false` value has happened. It you don't understand this, then I think [hotzst might have been right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962494/recursive-labyrinth-program-pathfinder/40962614?noredirect=1#comment69134362_40962494) and you don't understand recursion at all.