# Understanding execution behind recursion - how does recursion figure out when to stop?

Tags: javascript, recursion, theory

I know there are many threads for recursion here. And technically I do understand the principle behind recursion, I'm just more of curious as to where the **actual recursion counter is stored or how does the compiler keep track of it**

This is probably better understood by code. I have created a simple recursion function in javascript.

```
function factorial(number){
    if (number > 1) {
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
  } else {
    return number;
  }
}
```

Now, everybody understands how this works. We call a recursive function on the factorial which repeats recursively until a function end.

My question would be, how come the factorial function stops executing the recursion at the correct time? If we tried to debug the function in our mind, my understanding is, it would look something like this:

Let's say we called `factorial(3);`

> 1. Function Invoked -> Load Arguments
> 2. Calculcate the IF condition -> 3 > 1 -> apply recursive function
> 3. 3 * recursive(2) * recursive(1) => 3 * 2 * 1 = 6

Now my question is, how is that possible? How come a) if we reduced the recursive counter to 1, we didn't enter the `else {` statement given it should be evaluated as false, and b) how come the recursive counter knew, to loop the recursive function only number-Nth amount of times?

For better illustration, I added the following line of code
`document.write("entered with number " + number + "</br>");` so we'll print it out every time we enter the if condition.

```js
function factorial(number){
 if (number > 1) {
   document.write("entered with number " + number + "</br>");
   return number * factorial(number - 1);
  } else {
   return number;
  }
}

document.write(factorial(3) + "<br/>");
```

**As you can see, the if condition if condition evaluated as true and printed out the message for 3 and 2. How come the counter didn't loop lower and how come we never returned to the initial `else { return number; }` if we called the recursive operation on `factorial(2-1)`?**

It is pretty difficult question to word, so if you have any idea on how to formulate it better, feel free to edit my question!

Comment: `number` is the counter which counts descending. the exit condition checks it and returns this value.

Comment: Recursion is not so difficult once you understand how the local state gets pushed onto the stack when the recursive call happens and reloaded afterwards. Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25677330/5710637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a verbal description of what the recursion is doing, in too much detail:

1. You call `factorial(3)` in your `document.write()`.
2. `factorial(3)` wants to return `3 * factorial(2)`. Before it can return a value, it has to work out what `factorial(2)` means.
3. So now we have that `factorial(3)` waiting for the results of `factorial(2)`.   `factorial(2)` runs, and wants to return `2 * factorial(1)`. Before it can return a value it has to work out what `factorial(1)` means.
4. Now we have `factorial(3)` waiting for the results of `factorial(2)`, which is waiting for the results of `factorial(1)`.  `factorial(1)` runs, and sees that its input is 1, so hits the "else" block, so just returns 1 to its caller, the `factorial(2)`.
5. Now the `factorial(2)` has what it needs, so can return `2 * 1` to its caller, the `factorial(3)`.
6. Now the `factorial(3)` has what *it* needs, so can return `3 * 2` to its caller.
7. The calling `document.write` receives "6".

The recursion "knows" where to stop because eventually it reaches a point where it just returns the number 1, instead of returning something that depends on another call to `factorial()`.  If the function *always* tried to call itself, there'd be no way out of the recursion loop; it would just keep going until the stack overflows.

Except for `factorial(1)`, every call to `factorial(n)` will end up calling `factorial(n-1)` -- so note that `factorial(0)` or `factorial(-1)` or `factorial(1.01)` will never wind up reaching 1, so the recursion will just keep running until the stack overflows.  When writing recursive functions, it's a good idea to watch for and handle input that will never reach an exit point; in this case you'd want to throw an error if the input is anything other than a positive integer.

> How come the counter didn't loop lower and how come we never returned to the initial else { return number; } if we called the recursive operation on factorial(2-1)?

It did, but your `document.write` inside the function was inside the `if` block so nothing was printed when the function went into the `else` block instead.  Here's a more verbose version of the same function, which may give you a clearer picture of what happened:

```js
function factorial(number) {
  document.write("entered with number " + number + "<br>");
  if (number > 1) {
    document.write("recursing<br>")
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
  } else {
    document.write("Returning 1<br>")
    return number;
  }
}

document.write(factorial(3) + "<br>");
```

> what exactly determines when does recursion stop?  When the recursion of the function returns the same result twice (in this case 1?) or is there some different trigger?

Try not to think of this in terms of there being a "counter" of some sort keeping track of when the function should stop recursing, or a "trigger" that actively stops it -- that's a misleading way to look at it.  Each instance of the function knows only what input it received, and what it wants to return.  Most of the time what it wants to return happens to include a call to the same function, that's where the recursion comes from; when what it wants to return *doesn't* involve a function call, the recursion comes to an end.

For this particular function, for any input other than 1, it calls a new instance of itself with input n-1 (and waits for the results before it can return to its parent caller), so the recursion continues. For input of 1, it doesn't call itself, so the recursion ends.  That 'else' block is your "trigger" (though, again, that's a misleading way to think of it; it's not "triggering" anything, it's just returning a number instead of calling a function to return its results.)

`f(3)` calls `f(2)` which calls `f(1)` which doesn't call anything.  If you edited the function to call itself with `n+1` instead of `n-1`, then `f(3)` would call `f(4)` which would call `f(5)` and so on until you run out of memory.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this awesome insightful answer! Generally I think I comprehended the concept right, but had issue of understanding the internal counter and as to how the endpoint of the loop is calculated. Basically I understood as to why it needed to work (endless loop), but didn't as to how come it did. Perhaps another theoretical question to that, if we had (although I can't think of practical use) `factorial (number + 1)`  would there be any counter hard cap, similar to 1? Or would this just result in an endless recursion?

Comment: Perhaps better way to phrase that question, **what exactly determines when does recursion stop? When the recursion of the function returns the same result twice (in this case 1?) or is there some different trigger?**

Comment: That's a good question, I'll edit the answer to address that (it's a bit more than I can squeeze into a comment)

Comment: All clear now. Very nicely explained. Kind of baffling to me, because even when I searched for articles about recursion, all of them described how it worked, but none why it worked. Wish I could upvote your answer more than once, because it has some real potential to be a good learning material for other people to understand how it works better.