# Recursive calls in void function

Tags: c++, recursion

I run this C++ code and it prints "ABACABA" on the screen.Can someone give me a detailed explanation of how recursive calls work in this example? I can`t understand why i get that output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f( char c)
{
    if (c > 'A') f(c-1);

    cout << c;

    if (c > 'A') f(c-1);

}

int main()
{
    f('C');
}
```

Comment: Use debugger, or paper and pen.

Comment: Do you have a debugger you could step through it in? Or indeed drawing in a notebook?

Comment: What does `f('A')`? Same question for `f('B')`, and finally `f('C')`.

Comment: I don`t understand what that line after the cout does.I mean what is the order functions get called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding how recursive functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work)

Comment: I've enriched your code a bit: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7071f880d5acff6). Does this help?

Comment: The order in which they get called is f('C') f('B') f('A') f('A') f('B') f('A') f('A')

Comment: Translate it to a "mathematical" function: `f(C) 
      = f(B) C f(B)
      = f(A) B f(A) C f( A ) B f( A )
      = 0 A 0 B 0 A 0 C 0 A 0 B 0 A 0
      = ABACABA`

Answer (score 2):

- The ansi `char "C"` decremented is `"B"`. `C-- == B`
- The ansi `char "B"` decremented is `"A"`.  `B-- == A`

For the comparison:

- `B>A`
- `C>A`
- `C>B`

I think you can follow the logic better, if you introduce a second `std::cout` as

```
#include <iostream>

void f(char c) {
    std::cout << " start " << c << "\n";
    if (c > 'A')
        f(c - 1);
    std::cout << c;
    if (c > 'A')
        f(c - 1);
}

int main() {
    f('C');
    return 0;
}
```

The output than reads as:

```
 start C
 start B
 start A
AB start A
AC start B
 start A
AB start A
A
```

I also suggest, that you use a debugger to do tasks like that.

Comment: Pedantically `'A' + 1` is not guarantied to be `'B'`. (true for ansi and also for EBCDIC).