# Can someone explain for me how this recursion works?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is multiplication function that takes an array and n numbers of elements in the array and returns the multiplication of the N numbers of element in the array.

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
        if (n <= 0) 
        return 1;
        let first = multiply(arr, n - 1);
        console.log(`first value: ${first}`);
        console.log(typeof(first))
        let second = arr[n - 1];
        let result = first * second;
        return result;
      }
     const mul = multiply([1,2,3],2);
      console.log(mul)
```

How this recursion replace for or while loop?

Comment: Relevant: [Understanding how recursive functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25676961)

Comment: Take a pen and paper to trace the iteration. Create nodes and it is fairly easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The function `multiply` multiplies the last element of an array with `n` elements, i.e. `arr[n-1]` with the product of the previous elements of that array.

The "product of the previous elements" is calculated using `multiply` itself.

The recursion ends as soon as there are no elements left in the array. Then `1` is taken as the initial factor for the multiplication.