# Can someone explain this recursion problem to me? (Factorial)

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

**Edit - I have solved this problem but if its okay, I would like the experts here to still explain this problem so that other beginners could learn. You would do a way better job explaining.**

I'm trying to learn recursion and I kind of get the idea of recursion (dividing a big problem into smaller solutions and then combining them together. I have a few questions about this particular problem though. Factorial.

```
def fact(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)
```

The problem is, I don't know exactly how the calculation has been done after we reduce the n value by 1 on every recursion. For example, if n = 5, then the n value would go down by 1 every time (5,4,3,2,1). What I don't get is, what happens with those values? When are they actually multiplied up together? Can someone write the output or what's happening to the n value maybe step-by-step? I have tried to visualize this on PythonTutor, it was helpful but not very helpful.
[image]

If you guys feel as if this is a repeated question or very common, please link me to a source like (Youtube) where this is explained. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you already have a solution, it's possible to add an answer to your own question as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding how recursive functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work)

Comment: @DMalan I understand but since my knowledge on recursion is a bit wonky, it would be better coming from someone who understands better and explains better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question, i first need to bring you attention to two things that might happen in the program. of course the **Code under the IF** and the **code under the ELSE**. Keep it in your mind for now.

let's look at your questions : what happens with those values? When are they actually multiplied up together?.

now let's assume we have n = 3, so let's read the code under ELSE BLOCK (since n != 1) and see what happens.

we have `return n*fact(n-1)` and since n = 3,  --> `return 3*fact(3-1)`

and here is where you might start to see it, after this block and returning `3*fact(3-1)` nothing really gets calculated, you need to understand that THE IF STATEMENT is there for a reason. because if we don't have that IF BLOCK OF CODE we won't stop the recursion i.e : it will always return the function fact(...).

so what happens incrementally:

- fact(n=3) : n != 3 , **(ELSE BLOCK)**,  `return 3*fact(3-1)`
- fact(n=2) : n != 2 , **(ELSE BLOCK)**,  `return 3*2*fact(2-1)`
- fact(n=1) : n == 1 , **(IF BLOCK)**,  `return 1` (we return 1 instead of 1 so we stop and calculate all)

> fact(n=3) = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6

to sum up, what happens with those values, they get stacked together until last return statement (IF STATEMENT), then they get calculated.

Answer (score 1):

This recursion has its termination condition at n = 1.
This means it returns a constant value at n=1 and will not start another recursive call. If the n is `> 1` it will return `n*fact(n-1)`.

The calls for fact(5):

- `5*fact(4)`
- `5*(4*fact(3))`
- `5*(4*(3*fact(2)))`
- `5*(4*(3*(2*fact(1))))`
- `5*(4*(3*(2*1)))`

Comment: Thank you, straight to the point. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` condition is trivial, since 1! = 1, (I would've used `if n<=1`, since also 0! = 1). If the number N is greater than 1, the function returns that number multiplied by the result of the same function for N-1, so the function will iter over all integers until it gets to 1.

Suppose N=3:

- the `if` condition goes into the `else` part, since 3>1
- what the function return is 3 * fact(2), but what is fact(2)? is a function that returns 2 * fact(1), since 2>1
- so at the end what you get in return is 3 * 2 * fact(1), and knowing that fact(1) returns 1 (you activate the `if` condition), you obtain 6=3!

Hope this helped

Comment: Oh that was incredibly well explained. Thank you sir/madam!